# After Dr. Drake's Brain transplant, shouldn't Jessica be in Dr. Drake's body?

Tags: plot-explanation, friends

In Friends, *S07E15: The one with Joey's new Brain*, Joey explains to his friends that his character, Dr Drake Ramoray is getting a brain transplant and will be receiving Jessica Lockhart's brain. Ross clarifies that after the transplant, It will be Jessica in Drake's body and Joey confirms this.

However, in *S08E05: The one with Rachel's date*, Joey takes Rachel to the studio where they are shooting Days of our lives and we see Joey playing a scene with his co-star who is explaining that Drake's body is rejecting Jessica's brain. In this scene, it appears as if Joey is playing Drake rather than Jessica. He is seen wearing a Doctor's coat and also acts and talks like Drake. He seem's to understand the Doctor's "medical" explanation and responds by saying,

> That seems simple enough, why don't we just do that?

Also, the co-actor in the scene, who is also a doctor, refers to Jessica in third person, while technically, Jessica is standing right in front of him, in Drake's body.

Does this plot within a plot, have a plot hole?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The problem here is that we don't get to watch full and complete "episodes" of Joey's performance on Days of Our Lives, so we don't really have complete knowledge of what's happening to these characters, or what explanations might have been given for what's happening.  Without more details of the Days of Our Lives subplot in question, it's hard to say if there's a plot hole here or not.

- Maybe the transplant somehow resulted in a fusion of Jessica's and Drake's personalities (some nonsense about the soul being elsewhere than the brain, for example.)
- Maybe Jessica has been masquerading as Drake (this seems like the sort of thing that *always happens* with body-swap plot lines) and so the other characters in the scene addressed him as Drake because they thought he *was Drake*.
- Maybe saying "that seems simple, let's do that" was Jessica agreeing with the others precisely because she *doesn't understand what was said* and also doesn't want to blow her cover as "Drake," so she faked it.

The whole Drake Ramoray recurring subplot was a parody of soap operas and how ridiculous they can get IRL, so it's hardly a surprise things got a little cray-cray here.

Comment: Cray-cray indeed!